# Will there be any noticeable differences between Package installation vs Replication (At very first time of website publishing)

Tags: aem

Will there be any noticeable differences between Package Installation vs Replication. At very first time of website publishing after the completion of development which one will be good to consider either package installation or Replication.?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a package installation. Replication is done node by node and you might end up with just half package replicated if something goes wrong. uploading the package to your publish instance will eliminare this risk.

about time is hard to tell without knowing your infrastructure. it all depends in the network connecting the instances